# C# net5 WPF Desctop Программа не показывает сведения исключения

Tags: c#

Такой вопрос. Есть программа на net5. При возникновении ошибки программа просто закрывается.
Ошибку можно прочитать только в событиях.
Программа на net framework не закрывается а показывает окно где можно посмотреть сведения.
Программа запущенна самостоятельно а не из VS

Так и должно работать? Есть ли где опция включить чтобы в net5 показывало диалоговое окно с сведениями.

Я понимаю что нужно писать программы правильно и обрабатывать исключения. Но всякое бывает.

Просто бывает так. Пользователь далеко. Он звонит говорит вылетела программа. Не всем можно рассказать
посмотри события.  Проще сказать нажми сведения и пришли скриншот экрана.

Перещелкал все опции в свойствах проекта. Желаемого не добился.

Спасибо.

Comment: Есть типы исключений, которые нельзя перехватить. Например, StackOverflowException. Так что без деталей в вашем вопросе подсказать по сути нечего.

Comment: @tym32167 так какие детали? Пишем специально деление на ноль. Программа на framework показывает диалог ошибки. Программа на net5 просто вываливается полностью. Ошибку можно прочитать только в событиях windows. Все.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `Программа на net framework не закрывается а показывает окно где можно посмотреть сведения.` - на сколько я знаю, такое есть только на древнем WinForms. Хотите окно, пишите его сами, а лучше, делайте логирование!

Comment: @tym32167 пишем строчку. var a = 10 / 0; компилируем программу. Относим на другой комп. Запускаем. Скомпиленная под net вывалится просто с сообщением Прекращение работы программы. Если скомпилить под net framework то мы получим диалоговое окно с кнопкой сведения и можем прочитать текст ошибки.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо я понял. Значит это норма для net5. просто хотел убедиться что это не я не нашел кнопки включения такой опции.

Comment: Это норма и для framework. Сделайте например WPF проект, получите окно?

Comment: А и да, WinForms (.net 5) - [дал](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VR0M.png) окно. Так что не воспроизводится! И как я сказал выше, все зависит от проекта, что вы делаете, ибо такое поведение есть только у WinForms, если это будет например консоль, то она выведет сообщение в консоль и закроется если не ждете, если WPF - окна вы не увидите вовсе, если это asp.net, то выйдет страница с ошибкой.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ понял. Спасибо. Это только немного неудобно в том если пользователь далеко и не шарит в компах как понять где ошибка. Если я где то что-то упустил. Оборачивать прям все в try catch страхуясь от любой ошибки как то.. не знаю.

Comment: Есть события, которые происходят в момент необработанных исключений, погуглите, вещь полезная. А так, мое ИМХО, пользователь не должен видеть ошибки, он должен видеть сообщение, что что-то пошло не так, а ошибки, это лишь для вас инфа, не более. Так что как по мне, без этого окна даже лучше)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116473/discussion-between-manul74-and-evgeniyz).

Comment: @Alexander Petrov к сожалению не могу восстановить вопрос. Не могу найти где это. Написать занаво?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov не нашел. Но создал заново вопрос.  ответьте я засчитаю. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут дело не в фреймворке, а по большей части в том, какого типа проект у вас, ибо каждый по-своему реагируют на ошибки.

- **WinForms** - он выдаст окно с ошибкой (о чем вы и говорите), без разницы, будь у вас .net 5 или .net framework.
- **Консоль** - выдаст сообщение об ошибке в саму консоль и после закроется (если вы не ждете от пользователя действий).
- **WPF** - просто закроет проект, без вывода чего-либо (логи можно прочитать в журнале Windows).
- **Web** - эти проекты обычно выводят страницу, на которой подробная информация об ошибке.

Как видите, разные проекты имеют разные поведения. И мой вам тут совет, не выводите пользователю ошибку, выводите ему сообщение, ибо для большинства из них то, что будет на экране, это магия, неведомые писмина, которые им не понять. Пишите все эти ошибки в лог, который потом вам пользователь сможет, например передать, либо отправляйте эти ошибки на сервер (например AppCenter и его аналоги) чтоб мониторить онлайн, где именно у вас проблема.

А по поводу

> Оборачивать прям все в try catch страхуясь от любой ошибки как то.. не знаю.

Зачем? Если ошибка не обработана, то ее можно отловить при помощи специальных событий, у всех типов проектов они разные, но думаю вы без труда найдете их по запросу `[типПроекта] catch unhandled exceptions` в любом поисковике.

Comment: Спасибо catch unhandled exceptions для WPF все решил.